# How to get CSV file from URL with basic Auth using App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, basic-authentication, http-status-code-401, urlfetch

I want to know if I'm missing something. I am using google's sample code from their [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/features/third-party-apis):

```
  var username = "myUserName";
  var password = "myPsw";
  var url = "http://myurl.com/ReportServer?/ExternalData/SCCOfficeHuddleCount&rs:Format=CSV";
  
  var authHeader = 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(username + ':' + password);
  var options = {
    headers: {Authorization: authHeader}
  }

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

but still getting 401 - unauthorized. I don't know if I'm missing something.

I already validate that the URL is working. If I paste this URL below in the browser directly

```
http://user:psw@myurl.com/ReportServer?/ExternalData/SCCOfficeHuddleCount&rs:Format=CSV
```

I get the CSV file. So how can I do this using AppScript?

Comment: Does it work if you just fetch the same url you're using manually? `UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://user:psw@myurl.com/ReportServer?/ExternalData/SCCOfficeHuddleCount&rs:Format=CSV')`

Comment: @AaronDuniganAtLee No, It returns "Exception: Login information disallowed". It works if I paste the URL in another tab of the browser directly.

Comment: Your code looks correct, so I suspect it's an issue that the url in question is expecting a different form of authorization.  Can you confirm that basic auth with base64 of "username:password" is what it expects?  Sometimes you can tell by using the browser dev tools to inspect the headers that are sent with your successful browser request.

Comment: You might also try `encodeURI(url)` before fetching (in both your existing code, and in my previous suggestion), in case there are special characters in the url that need to be escaped.

Comment: Your url doesn't look right. What is the query parameter? Is `ReportServer?` supposed to be a path parameter? If so, the `?` should be encoded.

Comment: @AaronDuniganAtLee You were right! url in question was expecting a different form of authorization. The admin changed the config authentication from the server and now is working fine. Also I encoded the url like you said. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @TheMaster Yes, I encoded the URL, thanks for the help. The main issue was a config with the server auth.